# Link don't hide in rolling over menu

Tags: css

I have another problem. My second link from language menu (uppon right corner) don't hide:
 http://dash.com.pl/CTP/index.html
How You got a solution?

#### HTML

```
        <header id="language">
                <ul>
                 <li>

                 <div class="link"><a href="#">svensk</a><span></span></div>

                 <div id="sve"><a href="#"><div id="ico"></div></a></div>
                    <hr>
                <div class="link"><a href="#">english</a><span></span></div>

                 <div id="uk"><a href="#"></a></div>         
                </li>
            </ul>
            </header>
```

#### CSS

```
#language .link{

display:block;
    font-family: 'OpenSansRegular';
    font-size:14px;
    padding: 0 0 2px 0;
    cursor:pointer;
margin:0 0 0 33px;
}

#language .link a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#525252;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.4s ease;
margin:0;

}

#language .link a:hover{
    color:#fb6f5e;
}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS code here. As soon as the problem is fixed, the link (and thus the question) has no relevance any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this css style:

```
#language{
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change your html structure add unique class for li but for alternative u can use this code. Check it on firebug its working
solution css:

```
#language hr + .link { 
  display: none; 
}
#language ul:hover .link {
  display: block;
}
```